# Select rows with excat two same entries in a column

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe. And I want to select all the rows, where in one column I have two times the same value. So the dataframe looks like this:

```
group  value
A       1
A       2
B       3
B       1
B       4
C       1
C       1
D       4
D       5
D       3
D       2
```

And I want to filter it that this is the outcome:

```
group  value
A       1
A       2
C       1
C       1
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why is filtered `A` ?

Comment: because the group A has two entries. same for C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for counts values, compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['group'].map(df['group'].value_counts()).eq(2)]
```

Or use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('group')['group'].transform('size').eq(2)]
```

---

```
print (df1)
  group  value
0     A      1
1     A      2
5     C      1
6     C      1
```

Most clean, but unfortunately most slow is use [`DataFrameGroupBy.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df = df.groupby('group').filter(lambda x: len(x) == 2)
```