# Opposite of eq function python / select rows with more then two same entries in a column

Tags: python, pandas

this question is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62079564/select-rows-with-excat-two-same-entries-in-a-column).

But this time I want to filter a dataframe that I keep all the rows which have more then two same entries in a column.

For exact two columns I use: `df1 = df[df['group'].map(df['group'].value_counts()).eq(2)]`
and group is the column where the entries are located.
So I am searching for:

`df1 = df[df['group'].map(df['group'].value_counts()).uneq(2)]`

but this function doesn't exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for not equal:

```
df1 = df[df['group'].map(df['group'].value_counts()).ne(2)]
```

Here is list of all methods:

[`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html)  is `<`
[`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html)  is  `>`
[`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html)  is `<=`
[`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html)  is `>=`
[`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html)  is  `!=`
[`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html)  is `==`

Comment: thx, also when it is not part of the question, how to set it `>2`, so that I would also exclude `0,1`.